# How to build a vector based on the elements of another vector in Fortran?

Tags: arrays, fortran

I'm new to Fortran and would like to build a two vectors based on two other vectors. I will explain: The `kx` and `ky vector` has 150 elements. I want the vector `x_p(i,1)` to be a vector with 22500 elements, and I want each element of `kx` to be repeated 150 times, totalling 22500 elements. As for `x_p(i,2)`, I would like it to also have 22500 elements, but for `ky` to be repeated 150 times, totalling 22500 elements as well.

```
do i=1,150


     
    kx(i) = -2.0 + 4.0*((i-1.0)/(149.0))
    
    ky(i) = -2.0 + 4.0*((i-1.0)/(149.0))
     
    
    
enddo

do i=1,22500
  
  do a=1,150
  x_p(i,1)= kx(a)
  enddo  

enddo

do i=1,22500
  
  do a=1,150
  x_p(i,2)= ky(a)
  enddo  

enddo


do m=1,22500


    write(*,*)  x_p(i,1) ,  x_p(i,2)
        
enddo
```

I tried every way I could but was unsuccessful. I hope someone helps!

Comment: It's true. I will correct

Comment: It is better to use proper terminology. Fortran has arrays, not vectors.  It does have the `dot_product` and `matmul` functions, that make the 1D and 2D array sort of vectors and matrices in some use cases, but the proper terms is an array in Fortran.